# can anyone point me to a tutorial or explain how this photo is created using photoshop [double exposure effect]

Tags: photoshop

here is the link to the photo by Piotr Skoczylas that I saw on 500px.com

https://500px.com/photo/135874691/-the-way-i-am-by-piotr-skoczylas

I am really interested in finding out how he has done this or ideally point to a tutorial which explains the techniques using this in photoshop

Edit: I believe from reading the links in the post I marked as answer this effect is called double exposure. in an effort to appease the stackexchange police I am adding this so that anyone that comes across my question will know what I am referring to. I suppose the irony is that had I known it was called this I think I would have googled that and probably found it myself and not posted here asking.

Comment: Please see http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a modern example of doubly (or multiply) -exposed photos, when the same negative film frame was exposed multiple times with different scenes. This used to be done in-camera, or in the darkroom by stacking multiple negatives and exposing them onto the same photo paper.

With Photoshop, you want to use the Screen Blend mode. It's easiest to use source images with large contrast between the subject and the background;  a white or very light background is ideal, with no distracting elements. Using the Dodge tool, eliminate the undesired background from the portrait. Then, blend the non-portrait photo(s) (in this case, trees) with the portrait.

Example tutorials:

- [Digital Camera World double exposure tutorial](http://www.digitalcameraworld.com/2014/04/18/double-exposure-portraits-a-simple-tutorial-for-making-surrealist-images/) – this is a nice, simple example, very similar to the image you linked. This one is in color, and it makes a nice effect.
- [iPhone Photography School's interview with Brandon Kidwell](http://iphonephotographyschool.com/brandon-kidwell/) – this interview showcases lots of great shots by him, completely shot and processed on an iPhone (!). There are a couple double-exposure shots where he describes his composition and technique.

There are countless tutorials for this type of effect. Search Google for "photo double exposure blend tutorial" (or something similar). You will find more tutorials than you can go through.